# How to get a value of a non-alphanumeric key from and onChange event is JS/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

Not able to reference when user presses an enter or escape key.

I've created a calculator app.  I wanted the buttons and the keyboard to be usable.  Where my problem lies is figuring out how to reference the value of an enter key usage or an escape key usage.  the onChange event doesn't seem to give a value to those?

I'm using a class component in React for this...

my function that gets called onChange is:

```
handleKeyboard = (e) => {
    let userInput = e.target.value;
    console.log("beginning of handleKeyboard fx: ", userInput);
    this.setState({
        screenDisplay: userInput
    });
    this.userEntersNonNumber(e);
}
```

this function then accesses the following function to determine what to do when the user enters a non number....

```
userEntersNonNumber = (e) => {
    let userInput = e.target.value;
    if (userInput.includes("+") === true) {
        console.log('a plus sign was used');
        this.addition();
    } else if (userInput.includes("-") === true) {
        console.log('a minus sign was used');
        this.subtraction();
    } else if (userInput.includes("*") === true) {
        console.log('a multiplication sign was used');
        this.multiplication();
    } else if (userInput.includes("/") === true) {
        console.log('a division sign was used');
        this.division();
    } else if (userInput.includes("enter")) {
        console.log('the enter key was pressed');
/* I have a function that does the math which would be referenced here */
    } else if (userInput.includes("escape")) {
        console.log('the enter key was pressed');
/* I have a function that clears the calculator which would be referenced 
   here */
    } else {
        console.log('keep typing')
    }
}
```

where the function is called is:

the screenDisplay state is a way to display what the user has entered into the calculator thus far.  It is a string and with each key entered or button pushed, the value of that key/button gets added on to the end of the string.

The user should be able to use the enter key or the escape key on their keyboard to call the solve or clear functions which either calculate their entries or clears the calculator.  The buttons are operational, but the keystrokes are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` tags have another event listener called `onKeyDown` which is triggered when the user presses a key. You can create a brand new event-handler that handles logic for when the user presses the escape or enter key.

You just need to capture the keyCodes from the event, there are corresponding keyCodes for every key.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  handleKeyDown = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log("Enter action"); //replace with your code
    } else if (e.keyCode === 27){
      console.log("Escape action") //replace with your code
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <input onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} />;
  }
}
```

You can still use this event-listener in simultaneously with your existing `onChange` event.

Comment: Thank you so much!  It occurred to me I had to use the onKeyDown in conjunction with the onChange.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  I had to add an onKeyDown event to reference the userEntersNonNumber function to reference the value of the enter and escape keys.  Fixed it by:

```
<input className="screen" type="text" onChange={this.handleKeyboard} value={this.state.screenDisplay} **onKeyDown={this.userEntersNonNumber}**></input>
```

And:

```
userEntersNonNumber = (e) => {
    let userInput = e.target.value;
    **var x = e.key;**
    console.log("Key pressed: ", x);
    if (userInput.includes("+") === true) {
        console.log('a plus sign was used');
        this.addition();
    } else if **(x === 'Enter')** {
        console.log('the enter key was pressed');
        this.solve();        
    } else if **(x === 'Escape')** {
        console.log('the escape key was pressed');
        this.clearEntry();
    }
```